# org-ref completion of labels inside latex blocks

Tags: org-mode, latex

I recently started using **org-mode** to take academic notes, so I use LaTeX blocks (`#+BEGIN_LaTeX`) to insert LaTeX code using the special buffer that gives me code completion via **AuCTeX**. I also insert labels *inside* these blocks in order to be able to reference them later. I discovered that **org-ref** can help me do this easily, but the thing is I want to be able to see a list of labels that I currently have on my file that I can choose from whenever I want to reference an equation.

When I do `C-c C-l` to call `org-insert-link` and choose *eqref*, I'm not able to see all my labels or get any sort of completion for my labels. When I have a large number of labels, I can't remember what I labeled a particular equation with and so I need some way to keep track of all these labels. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Wasn't there something like `org-ref-list-of-<something>` command?

Comment: @wvxvw Yes, I found `org-ref-list-of-figures` and `org-ref-list-of-tables`, but I don't have any figures or tables in my org file to test it. My problem at the moment has to do with labels associated with equations inside LaTeX blocks. But I also found `org-ref-helm-insert-ref-link` and `org-ref-helm-insert-label-link`, which I believe is what I need (although not sure) but they are bound to menu bar buttons and nothing else. I don't use the menu-bar.

Comment: Well, you can always bind them to something else. I'm not familiar with Helm, so I don't know what they do. But you could always test those by just running `M-x` followed by the name of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this problem through the use of `org-ref-helm-insert-ref-link` which shows all the labels (regardless of whether they are inside latex code blocks or outside them) you have in your org file and anything surrounding that label for context. This, of course, requires the `org-ref` package to be installed, but I already had it and didn't know about this functionality before.